# how to apply css change to only this object in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

This code is working great in terms of resizing a custom shadow to the height of an image. But if I apply it to different sized images on the page, it's resizing all of them to the first image size. How do I make it more specific? Blanking on the syntax.

```
  <li class="col third impact-home">         
      <div class="image-with-overlay">
        <%= image_tag 'impact.jpg', :class => "image-with-shadow" %>
        <div class="image-shadow"></div>
      </div>
  </li>   

$(document).ready( function() { //Fires when DOM is loaded
    getImageSizes();
    $(window).resize(function() { //Fires when window is resized
        getImageSizes();
    });
});

function getImageSizes() {
    var imgHeight = $(".image-with-shadow").height();
    var imgMargin = (- imgHeight) * .995;
    console.log(imgMargin);
    $(".image-shadow").css({"height": imgHeight});
    $(".image-shadow").css({"margin-top": imgMargin});
}
```

Comment: Hope you know that you're acquiring the size of the 1st's object's parameters from the array of objects in `$(".image-with-shadow")`. To make it simple, add it in a loop and this will work as required

Comment: You can also make a jquery plugin then use it for any specific image. For Plugin Documentation check this (https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation)

Comment: This is meaningless without HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through each image and handle them individually. without the html i dont know how `.image-shadow` relates to the image itself but it could look something like this

```
function getImageSizes() {
        $(".image-with-shadow").each(function () {
            var imgHeight = $(this).height();
            var imgMargin = (- imgHeight) * .995;
           console.log(imgMargin);
           //need to select the image shadow in relation to each image
           //with no HTML reference i'm not sure how it's laid out
           $(this).closest(".image-shadow").css({"height": imgHeight});
           $(this).closest(".image-shadow").css({"margin-top": imgMargin});
    })

}
```

Comment: i got it working with             $(this).next().css({"height": imgHeight});